# Finding all Audio Links in a page using python

Tags: python, audio, hyperlink, find

**I want to find all the audio files like .mp3 , .wav , .ogg ,.wma etc in a site Using Python .
This is my code >>**

```
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    content = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile('http.*\.mp3'))]
    print (str(len(links)) + " Audios Found ")
   # print (links)
    print("\n".join(links))
```

**This will Find only .mp3 links .
I want other audio links also .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using regex to choose the links, change this line

```
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile('http.*\.mp3'))]
```

to

```
links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile('http.*\.(mp3|wav|ogg|wma)'))]
```